# How to put this JavaScript code into a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this piece of code who kinda follows a pattern but I don't know how to make it a loop to simplify.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.classList.add("show-el-1");
    wrapper.classList.add("hide-el-0");
}, 600);

setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.classList.add("show-el-2");
    wrapper.classList.add("hide-el-1");
}, 1800);

setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.classList.add("show-el-3");
    wrapper.classList.add("hide-el-2");
}, 3000);

setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.classList.add("show-el-4");
    wrapper.classList.add("hide-el-3");
}, 4200);
```

It adds 1200 in every `setTimeout` duration, and changes the `show-el-x` and `hide-el-y` numbers.

Comment: Consider setInterval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: wouldn't setInterval for doing something at fixed time intervals, not incremental time intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    setTimeout(() => {
        wrapper.classList.add("show-el-" + (i + 1));
        wrapper.classList.add("hide-el-" + i);
    }, 600 + i * 1200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you going

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const delay = 600 + (i * 1200)
  setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.classList.add("show-el-" + (i + 1));
    wrapper.classList.add("hide-el-" + i);
  }, delay);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep this running i.e. updating class after every timeout, then you could go for recursive approach as the snippet below, else for loop could be a more readable and easy to understand solution

```js
let newTimeout = 600;
let firstClass= 1;
const func1 = () => {
    wrapper.classList.add(`show-el-${firstClass}`);
    wrapper.classList.add(`hide-el-${firstClass -1}`);
    newTimeout += 1200;
    firstClass += 1;
    setTimeout(func1, newTimeout);
};
setTimeout(func1, newTimeout);
```

Comment: Did you recognize that the class names change too?

Comment: fixed it. didn't notice earlier